# Neo4j cypher to count and display all the relationship between two given nodes

Tags: java, graph, playframework, neo4j, cypher

Here I am using neo4j rest api,
in first step I want to collect information like how many relationships are there between two given nodes.

Sample : `MATCH (n:Node {id: {parameter1}})-[r:someType]-(m:Node {id: {parameter2}}) RETURN COUNT(r)`

Then I would like to collect all the values assigned to the edges so I can calculate further calculations. I need all the different types of relationships and their properties between two given nodes.

If it is possible I would like to do it in single cypher.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then I would like to collect all the values assigned to the edges

```
MATCH (n:Node {id: {parameter1}})-[r:someType]-(m:Node {id: {parameter2}})
RETURN COUNT(r) AS count, COLLECT(r) AS rels
```

Note that the only thing I changed was adding `collect(r) AS rels` to the return, which gives you a collection of `Relationship` objects representing all edges with label `someType` between these nodes.

To get all edges of any type:

```
MATCH (n:Node {id: {parameter1}})-[r]-(m:Node {id: {parameter2}})
RETURN COUNT(r) AS count, collect(r) AS rels ORDER BY labels(r)
```

Remove the label requirement from the `MATCH` to return a collection of all relationships of any type. Order that collection by label, so that the list of relationships returned is sorted by type, making it easy for you to distinguish between them as needed for the purposes of your "further calculations"

*This code is untested, and I'm not 100% sure you can call labels on a collection. If not, let me know and I'll provide an alternate solution*.

Comment: Hey thanks drewmore! Here rels is array right, How can I access neo4j array into java output, any clue ?

Comment: @SagiruddinMondal rels is a collection of all the relationships matching the query, yes. As for your other question, assuming you're asking "how can I convert a collection of `Relationship` objects into an array of objects of your class - that's a very large question. Your strategy for doing so will be very much a part of your overall design strategy. See [this tutorial](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/tutorials-java-embedded-entities.html) on domain modeling, it helped me alot.