# Neo 4j - How to count the number of times two relationships appear in the same nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Suppose I have 3 nodes A, B and C, and two relationships r1 and r2, how can I count the number of times that the two relationships occur on the same nodes? For example:

```
A-[r1]-B
A-[r2]-B

A-[r1]-C
B-[r1]-C
B-[r2]-C
```

As you can see, r1 appears 3 times and r2 two times, but on the same nodes we have A-[r1:r2]-B and B[r1:r2]-C, so the count value I'm looking for is 2, because both A and B, B and C have the two relations between them.

For the possible duplicate, I'm not interested on count the number of times the relationship occurs between two nodes, I want to count all the times this happens.
Sorry about my English and thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Neo4j cypher to count and display all the relationship between two given nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105454/neo4j-cypher-to-count-and-display-all-the-relationship-between-two-given-nodes)

Comment: @Tezra Hi, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. Your graph

For the ease of possible further answers and solutions I note my graph creating statement:

```
CREATE
  (a:NodeA {name: 'A'})-[:RelationType1]->(b:NodeB {name: 'B'}),
  (a)-[:RelationType2]->(b),
  (a)-[:RelationType1]->(c:NodeC {name: 'C'}),
  (b)-[:RelationType1]->(c),
  (b)-[:RelationType2]->(c);
```

[image: YourGraph]

## 2. Render occurrences

### 2.1 Solution

```
MATCH
  (startNode)-[:RelationType1]-(endNode)-[:RelationType2]-(startNode)
  WHERE
  id(startNode) < id(endNode)
RETURN
  startNode.name AS startNodeName, endNode.name AS endNodeName;
```

The `id` comparison in the `WHERE` clause of line 4 avoids having two relationships per pair (one in each direction) and prevents creating the relationship from nodes to themselves.

### 2.2 Results

```
╒═══════════════╤═════════════╕
│"startNodeName"│"endNodeName"│
╞═══════════════╪═════════════╡
│"A"            │"B"          │
├───────────────┼─────────────┤
│"B"            │"C"          │
└───────────────┴─────────────┘
```

## 3. Count occurrences

### 3.1 Solution

```
MATCH
  (startNode)-[:RelationType1]-(endNode)-[:RelationType2]-(startNode)
  WHERE
  id(startNode) < id(endNode)
RETURN
  count(startNode) AS amount;
```

### 3.2 Result

```
╒════════╕
│"amount"│
╞════════╡
│2       │
└────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be the right way to do! I'll give a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean "number of times 2 nodes have exactly 2 relationships between them", but the idea here is to keep the Cypher simple so that the pattern you are matching is pretty plug-and-play. You can use SIZE to count the occurrences of a specific pattern between nodes, and EXISTS to test if it simply exists. Here we are using the where to find the node pairs that adhere to the pattern we are interested in, and then we return the number of rows as the count of the occurrences of that pattern.

```
MATCH (a), (b)
WHERE ID(a) > ID(b) // create distinction between a and b
AND SIZE((a)--(b)) = 2 // match the pattern we are looking for between them
RETURN COUNT(*) as occurrences // return count
```

The pattern could also be `EXISTS((a)-[:r1]-(b)-[:r2]-(a))` (note that `WHERE EXISTS((a)--(b))` is equivalent to `WHERE (a)--(b)`, but the first form is a little more clear)

Comment: There are other relationships on the database,  I need to be able to specify the two relationships that I want to check if exists at the same time on the same nodes

Comment: @WolganEns Just replace the pattern in the query with the one you want to match. If you don't need to check the pattern occurrence rate per pair, just use `EXISTS()` instead of `SIZE() = #`. I already gave the EXISTS form where you specify the relation types, so I'm not sure exactly what the pattern you are trying to count is.

Comment: Note that this solution involves a cartesian product - won't be optimal with big graphs.